# multiple linker flags xcode

Tags: objective-c, static-libraries, xcode7, google-signin

I am trying to add GoogleSignIn to an app which had been using GTMOAuth2 sign in.
I am trying to add -ObjC to my "other linked flags" in my Build Settings however I already am linking lxml2 for Facebook.  How can I have multiple linked flags.

I am having problems having the app recognized my GoogleServices-info.plist.
whenever I try to open the ViewController which calls for the GoogleSignIn it gives me this error

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d20650'

I created the plist using the developer site it is a root file
I connected it to my target
I placed it and GoogleSignIn.bundle into target/build phases/copy bundle resources
I imported GoogleSignIn.framework and GoogleSignIn.bundle
I added GoogleSignIn.framework, AddressBook.framework,StoreKit.framework, and SystemConfiguration.framework to my project
I added URL Types of my bundle identifier and revered Client id
I #import  to the .h file of the viewController I wish to have call this
I put GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.clientID = my client Id found in the GooleServices-Info.plist in  ViewDidLoad in that viewController

I have tried to put the GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.clientID = in my app Delegate but then the app crashes when if first opens up with the same error message

Like I said earlier I think if I could include the -ObjC to my other linked flags this would work.

in Other Linker Flags I just tried

debug  -lxml2 -ObjC
release -lxml2 -ObjC
  any Architecture|any SDK   -lxml2 -ObjC

However then I get the error Linker command failed with exit code 1

I am also getting multiple duplicate symbols for Architecture arm 7

Answer (score 2):

You do not say how you are attempting to enter the multiple flags. According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW76) they are space-separated. If you are using spaces edit your question to provided further details of exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

So I got this working When I added the -ObjC to the other linker flags I got a lot of duplicate symbols
I deleted a number of the original GTMHTTP.m files because by linking the libGDataTouchStaticLib.a it has a number of these files that are a combination of the .h and .m files as I understand it.  So by deleting the .m files I got rid of the duplicate symbols and when I have gotten rid of all of those I got rid of the exit code 1 and the app ran ok.  Now I have a problem with a 401 error when trying to upload a video.  Will put this in another question.